# Where are all islands and discoverable locations?

Tags: simpleplanes

After taking off in Simpleplanes and flying around over the ocean for a while, I've found a lots of tiny islands all over the place, and a few really big ones that unlock new spawn locations once found.  Large islands appear to also have many discoverable 'locations' around them as well, like airports, carriers, or landmarks.  These locations automatically become available as start points once discovered.

Where can I find all of these major islands, and once there, where should I look to unlock all of the locations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure this map covers all major islands (including Kraken)

https://www.reddit.com/r/SimplePlanes/comments/4ow1b4/i_made_a_map_of_the_simpleplanes_world/

Map: [image: Map]